# How to find the curve that minimizes distance?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations

My idea was to derive equations that describes the curve, embedded to a surface, that gives the minimum distance between two points, with the cartesian basis (hence not needing to use the metric tensor). Let's define a parametric curve as:
$$
\mathbf r(\tau) = x(\tau)\mathbf i + y(\tau)\mathbf j  + z(x(\tau), y(\tau))\mathbf k
$$
This is the integral that gives the arclength of the curve:
$$
S =\int_{x_0}^{x_1} {dr} \\
d \mathbf r = d\tau \left (\frac{dx}{d\tau}\mathbf i + \frac{dy}{d\tau}\mathbf j  + \frac{dz}{d\tau}\mathbf k \right ) \\
dr = \sqrt{d \mathbf r \cdot d \mathbf r} = d \tau\;\sqrt{\left (\frac{dx}{d\tau} \right)^2 + \left (\frac{dy}{d\tau} \right)^2 + \left (\frac{dz}{d\tau} \right)^2}
$$
Arriving to:
$$
S = \int_{x_0}^{x_1} {d \tau\;\sqrt{\left (\frac{dx}{d\tau} \right)^2 + \left (\frac{dy}{d\tau} \right)^2 + \left (\frac{dz}{d\tau} \right)^2}}
$$
And to find minimal distance you just vary the functional and set it equal to $0$:
$$
\delta S = \delta \int_{x_0}^{x_1} {d \tau\;\sqrt{\left (\frac{dx}{d\tau} \right)^2 + \left (\frac{dy}{d\tau} \right)^2 + \left (\frac{dz}{d\tau} \right)^2}} \\
\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{...}} \;\left ( 2\frac{dx}{d\tau} \frac{d^2x}{d\tau^2} + 2\frac{dx}{d\tau} \frac{d^2y}{d\tau^2} + 2\frac{dz}{d\tau} \frac{d^2z}{d\tau^2} \right)\;\delta \tau =0 
$$
Then we find this equation:
$$
\frac{dx}{d\tau} \frac{d^2x}{d\tau^2} + \frac{dx}{d\tau} \frac{d^2y}{d\tau^2} + \frac{dz}{d\tau} \frac{d^2z}{d\tau^2} =0 
$$
If we try to interpret this equation we find out that the velocity vector at which a particle is moving must be perpendicular to the acceleration vector:
$$
\frac{d \mathbf r}{d \tau} \cdot \frac{d^2 \mathbf r}{d \tau^2} = 0
$$

But how should I solve this. Is a system of differential equations with 3 unknowns but only one equation. How would I solve for specific surfaces, like a plane, a paraboloid, etc. How do I plug a parametric surface in the equation, like: $(u, v, u + v)$ What other requisites should I impose to solve the problem. Should I use the Euler-Lagrange Equations?

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate"? Geodesic equations typically cannot be solved using elementary functions. Are you asking about numerical solutions?

Comment: @MoisheKohan just find the differential equation (or set of differential equations) for different surfaces, for example for a plane, or a paraboloid, etc. (my bad for saying "calculate").

Comment: Then edit the question to make it clear. The correct equation involves the equation of the surface, do you have the surface equation in parametric form or in the form of a level set? This should be also added to the question. And, yes, all you need is to know about the induced Levi-Civita connection, the metric tensor is not needed.

Comment: If you use Cartesian distance with respect to coordinates, then the answer is easy. The shortest curves are just straight line segments.

Comment: @Deane but if the particle is restricted to a surface?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't read your question carefully enough. I assumed you were using coordinates on the surface. Since you are using the coordinates in 3-space, then you are in fact implicitly using a metric tensor. Nowhere in your calculations are you using the equations for the surface itself. How do you want specify the surface? As a parameterized surface? Or as the zero set of a function?

Comment: If you use a parameterized surface, you will end up with the same formulas that you would get using a metric tensor on the surface. If you specify the surface as $f = 0$, then it will be a constrained optimization problem and you'll need to use Lagrange multipliers. That will probably lead you to the condition that the geodesic curvature must be zero.